# How do I write a partitioned parquet file from a big query table?

Tags: google-bigquery, parquet, partition, google-cloud-storage

I have created a parquet file from a big query table like this:

```
 EXPORT DATA
    OPTIONS(
             uri='gs://path_for_parquet_file/*.parquet',
             format='PARQUET',
             overwrite=false
            )
  AS SELECT * FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table`;
```

I want to know if there is a way to partition the parquet file. My big query table is partitioned by a date column.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

could not found answer to this question from official docs.
my solution to this is write for loop to filter partiotion  and export them

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is supported unfortunately